# Hartshorne II-3.22(b)

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry, dimension-theory-algebra

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a dominant morphism of integral schemes of finite type over a field $k$.

> Let $e=\dim(X)-\dim(Y)$. For any point $y\in f(X)$, show that every irreducible component of the fibre $X_y$ has dimension $\geq e$. [Hint: Let $Y'=\overline{\{y\}}$ and use (a) and Ex. 3.20b]

I think there is a typo and we have to use Ex 3.20d, which says that if $Y$ is a closed subset of $X$ then $\dim(Y)+\mathrm{codim}(Y,X)=\dim(X)$. In addition, (a) says that if $Y'$ is a closed irreducible subset of $Y$ whose generic point $\eta'$ is contained in $f(X)$ and $Z$ is any irreducible componet of $f^{-1}(Y')$ such that $\eta'\in f(Z)$, then $\mathrm{codim}(Z,X)\leq\mathrm{codim}(Y',Y)$.

**What I have done**

By exercise 3.10a, $X_y$ is homeomorphic to $f^{-1}(y)$ with the induced topology, so I'm trying to show the result for $f^{-1}(y)$ since it looks easier, but using the hint I've only managed to prove it for $f^{-1}(Y')$. This is my proof:

Since $y$ is obviously the generic point of $Y'$, if we take $Z$ to be an irreducible component of $f^{-1}(Y')$ containing $y$, by (a) we have

$$\operatorname{codim}(Z,X) \leq \operatorname{codim}(Y',Y)$$

Now Ex 3.20d implies

$$\dim (X) - \dim (Z) \leq \dim (Y) - \dim (Y')$$

and thus

$$e = \dim (X) - \dim (Y) \leq \dim (Z) - \dim (Y') \leq \dim (Z)$$

But this only shows that any irreducible component of $f^{-1}(Y')$ has dimension $\geq e$. How can I conclude that this is true also for the irreducible components of the fibre $f^{-1}(y)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $W$ be an irreducible component of $X_y$, and let $k$, $k'$ be the codimensions of $\overline{W}$ (closure in $X$) in $X$ and $Y'$ in $Y$, respectively.

One argues that $\overline{W}$ is an irreducible component of $f^{-1}(Y’)$. Thus $k \leq k'$ by part (a).

Applying Ex. 3.20b and using the additivity of transcendence degrees in towers, we see that $$\text{dim}(W)=e+k'-k \geq e.
$$

Comment: In general the preimage of the closure is not the closure of the preimage. Why do we know that $\overline{f^{-1}(y)}=f^{-1}(Y')$? In principle we only have inclusion to the right since $f^{-1}(Y')$ is a closed subset containing $f^{-1}(y)$. Equality only holds if $f$ is closed.

Comment: I took that part out (it was not important).

Comment: Ok I'll try to fill the details

Comment: I have a doubt about the transcendence degrees. I actually don't know  which tower you're using  to get the last equality.

Comment: The tower is $F/K/k$, where $F$ is the function field of
$W$ and $K$ is the residue field of $y$.

Comment: Why is $\overline{W}$ an irreducible component in $f^{-1}(Y')$? I still can't see this. Javi, did you ever solve this?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOrtiz The closure of an irreducible subset is irreducible; $f^{-1}(Y')$ is closed and contains $W$.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOrtiz Moreover, if $\overline{W}$ is contained by an irreducible component $T$ of $f^{-1}(Y')$ whose generic point is $\nu$, then I claim that $f(\nu)=y$.  Indeed, $f(T) \subset Y'$ is a dense inclusion of irreducible subsets, so the generic point of $Y'$ is both $y$ and $f(\nu)$. Next I claim that $\nu \in W$. Indeed, the closure of $\lbrace \nu \rbrace$ in $X_y$ is irreducible and contains $W$. In conclusion, we see that $T = \overline{\lbrace \nu \rbrace}\subset\overline{W}$ (these overlines denote closures in $X$, or equivalently $f^{-1}(Y')$).

Comment: @Oven Why do the function field of $W$ and the function field of $\bar W$ have the same transcendence degree over $k$?

Comment: @yuan Those function fields are equal, because $W$ is dense in $\overline{W}$.